# XSLT book display multiple authors

Tags: xml, xslt

I want the html to display the book twice, once with the first author and the second time with the second author. With this code the first and last name are missing. Is there a way to to that?
The xml file looks like this:

```
<books>
    <book>
        <authors>
            <author>
                <firstname>AuthorName1</firstname>
                <lastname>AuthorLastName1</lastname>
            </author>
        <author>
                <firstname>AuthorName2</firstname>
                <lastname>AuthorLastName2</lastname>
        </author>
        </authors>
        <name>BookName</name>
        <year>2010</year>
    </book> 
</books>
```

and the xslt looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Books</title>
</head>
 <body>
     <xsl:for-each select="books/book">
       <p> FirstName:</p><xsl:value-of select="firstname" />
       <p>LastName:</p><xsl:value-of select="lastname" /> 
       <p>Book:</p><xsl:value-of select="name" /> 
       <p>Year:</p><xsl:value-of select="year" />
     </xsl:for-each>
 </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is not clear.

Please try the following XSLT.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/books">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Books</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                    <xsl:for-each select="book/authors/author">
                        <p>FirstName: <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></p>
                        <p>LastName: <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/></p>
                        <p>Book: <xsl:value-of select="../../name"/></p>
                        <p>Year: <xsl:value-of select="../../year"/></p>
                    </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is your reason for dividing the `for-each` operation into two instead of `<xsl:for-each select="book/authors/author">`?

Comment: @y.arazim, you are right. I adjusted the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it might be more efficient to eliminate the repeated walk up and down the tree and do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
      <head>
         <title>Books</title>
      </head>
      <body>
         <xsl:for-each select="books/book">
            <xsl:variable name="book">
               <p>Book:</p><xsl:value-of select="name"/>
               <p>Year:</p><xsl:value-of select="year"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="authors/author">
               <p>FirstName:</p><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>
               <p>LastName:</p><xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
               <xsl:copy-of select="$book"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
   </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```